# Repeat pandas dataframe over time

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import pdb, random

dates = pd.date_range('1950-01-01', '1950-12-31', freq='D')
data  = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(len(dates))]
cum_data = pd.Series(data, index=dates)
```

How do I repeat this dataframe over the next 10 years?

Comment: What would you do for leap year days? All years will not have equal days.

Comment: Either fill them with 0 or same value as 1950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

For each year in the list of years you provide, I extend the data by the same initial dataset unless it is a leap year.

On a leap year, I insert the entry defined by `fill_leap` at the 60th day (31 days in January + 29 days in February on a leap year)

```
import pandas as pd
import pdb, random

def multiYearData(data, start_y, until_y, fill_leap):
    def leapyr(n):
        if n % 4 != 0:
            return False
        elif n % 100 != 0:
            return True
        elif n % 400 != 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    multi_year = []
    for y in range(start_y,until_y):
        if leapyr(y):
            multi_year.extend( data[:60] + [fill_leap] + data[60:] )
        else:
            multi_year.extend(data)
    return multi_year

start_y = 1950
until_y = 1960

dates = pd.date_range(str(start_y)+'-01-01', str(until_y-1)+'-12-31', freq='D')

data  = [int(1000.*random.random()) for i in xrange(365)]
data = multiYearData(data, start_y, until_y, fill_leap=100000)

cum_data = pd.Series(data, index=dates)
```

I borrowed the `leapyr()` function from [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23849757/4013571).

Using `fill_leap=100000` you can check the leap years are correctly defined:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

This works.

It uses a dictionary comprehension to fill a random number for each day in each month (2012 was a leap year, so it includes a random number which will be applied to all Feb. 29 leap year dates).

The method then creates a Pandas Series my looking up the random number for each month and day based on the date index.

```
from calendar import monthrange
from numpy.random import rand

start_date = pd.Timestamp('1950-1-1')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
data_dict = {m + 1: {d + 1: rand() 
                     for d in range(monthrange(2012, m + 1)[1])} 
             for m in range(12)}
cum_data = pd.Series(map(lambda x: data_dict.get(x.month).get(x.day), dates), index=dates)
```

**Example Output**

```
>>> {d.year: v for d, v in cum_data.iteritems() if d.month == 12 and d.day==31}
{1950: 0.66380331904182033,
 1951: 0.66380331904182033,
 1952: 0.66380331904182033,
 1953: 0.66380331904182033,
 1954: 0.66380331904182033,
 1955: 0.66380331904182033,
 1956: 0.66380331904182033,
 1957: 0.66380331904182033,
 1958: 0.66380331904182033,
 1959: 0.66380331904182033}

>>> cum_data.iloc[:10]
1950-01-01    0.539305
1950-01-02    0.358602
1950-01-03    0.388185
1950-01-04    0.089234
1950-01-05    0.523388
1950-01-06    0.983208
1950-01-07    0.882484
1950-01-08    0.597809
1950-01-09    0.797835
1950-01-10    0.484002
Freq: D, dtype: float64

>>> side_by_side(cum_data['1952-2-25':'1952-3-1'], 
                 cum_data['1953-2-25':'1953-3-1'], 
                 cum_data['1956-2-25':'1956-3-1'])
1952-02-25    0.711973     1953-02-25    0.711973     1956-02-25    0.711973 
1952-02-26    0.480222     1953-02-26    0.480222     1956-02-26    0.480222 
1952-02-27    0.558472     1953-02-27    0.558472     1956-02-27    0.558472 
1952-02-28    0.058541     1953-02-28    0.058541     1956-02-28    0.058541 
1952-02-29    0.019080     1953-03-01    0.430778     1956-02-29    0.019080 
1952-03-01    0.430778     Freq: D, dtype: float64    1956-03-01    0.430778 
Freq: D, dtype: float64                               Freq: D, dtype: float64
```